# Power bi snowflake Default_role setting

Tags: azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to set default roles to all user that belong to specific role ?

I can manually alter the role to default for one user at a time, but it is time consuming and people come and go.

Comment: You could write a stored procedure that runs in a task that looks for all users that have that role granted to them, and set their default role to that role.  Might be annoying for users that don't really want that role to be their default, though.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: Setting the default role for multiple users within one statement isn't possible. It isn't possible to mention multiple users within one single ALTER USER-statement: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-user.html

Alternative solutions are:

1. Use Mike Walton's idea in the comments of your question and create a procedure that selects all users of a certain role and generates/executes an ALTER-statement for every user within the procedure (I like that one)
2. I once had a similar problem and created an Excel-sheet for all my users and roles. Here I maintained which user belonged to which role and used Excel to generate all my corresponding CRAETE ROLE, CREATE USER, GRANT ROLE and also ALTER USER-statements. So Excel generates the code based on your USER-ROLE-matrix and then you can paste the code to Snowflake. (Of course then you can extend and adapt that "excel code generator" for your use cases etc.)

Kind regards :-)

Comment: We will go with the scenario, that if an individuals wants default role or needs one, he/she will do the command itself. Most simple way. Thanks for the contribution!

ALTER USER user SET DEFAULT_ROLE=mydefautlrole;

Comment: Most simple way, exactly :)